# How to disable ASP.NET 404 message

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I see so many people are complaining that IIS is overriding ASP.NET custom error messages.
However my problem is other way round. My IIS is not overriding the ASP.NET `The resource cannot be found.` or 404 error message.

Our web server is hosting multiple types of document types and we already have a specific 404 page created in IIS (non-aspx). In Web.config we need to turn on

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" />
```

so we can handle errors caused by different situations like un-handled exceptions. This allows ASP.NET to grab all errors related to aspx including 404. for example if I call a page like `wew232sdsd.aspx` that obviously does not exists in my server. I will receive a 404 message from ASP.NET (Yellow screen) instead of IIS 404 message.

**Question:**

How can I divert back ASP.NET 404 message back to IIS

Comment: refer these articles....
http://www.braintrove.com/id/46

http://blog.osbornm.com/2011/05/27/asp-net-404-custom-errors-and-iis/

Comment: @tarzanbappa, This is not answering my question. I want ASP.NET does not reply to 404 message. your links are about how making ASP.NET reply to 404